# iPhone - Second target does not seem to call App Delegate methods

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, appdelegate

I have a second target in my Xcode project that I use to run a different scheme and have a few different libraries included. The target runs fine, and I get all the correct output from it, except when I try to make a check in the App Delegate. I am checking the Bundle Name in **ApplicationDidEnterBackground** (user hits the home button) and then doing something, but it does not seem to be called.

If I run the original/regular target, it is called just fine and the check is made. How do I get the App Delegate methods to be called on a separate target? I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Did you check if creating the new target created a new file with a new different App Delegate class?

Comment: I don't see any new files. I'll check the actually project folder on disk though to be extra sure

Comment: no new files created by the second target